# Responsive grid with masonry

Tags: responsive-design, grid, sass, margins, masonry

I want to build a responsive masonry grid like [THIS](http://tympanus.net/codrops/collective/collective-57/)

I have this HTML

```
<div class="js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "gutter": 20 }'>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
</div>
```

and the SCSS

```
article{
width: 100%;
float: left;

    @include breakpoint(medium) {
        width: 50%;
    }

    @include breakpoint(large) {
        width: 33.33333%;
    }
}
```

When I remove the gutter daclared in the html the grid works as I want, but with it it displays 2 at the large breakpoint and 1 at medium. How can I get this to work with using margins to space out the article horizontally?

Comment: To get mine to work, I had to use box-sizing:border-box, combined with sizes no more than 1 decimal point AND even then, 50% wouldn't work all the time until I made it 49.9% and there is an option called .gutter-size. It was a royal pain to get it to work with a fluid and responsive layout. I must have read the docs 10 times and tried all Dezandro's CodePens.

Comment: In addition the images loaded plugin AND the google font loader had to be included (all of this is explained in the extensive documentation) since without them fonts and images on load would make the layout not layout correctly until those are loaded with the script.

Comment: @Christina Thanks for your comments, I found the answer below to be the correct one. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that masonry.js adds a margin to the element making the element 50% + 20px wide, with is to big to fit on one row.

The solution is to make the elements and gutter fit in your wrapper by making the gutter + elements in a row = wrapper. If you have a flexible layout this would be a problem as masonry.js only takes a fixed px as gutter size.

So if (like in you example) you make the elements a fixed width this would be no problem. But masonry.js has a solution; if you sett the gutter not to a fixed width but to a element, masonry.js will use the width of that element. So a flexible solution could be to do this:

```
<div class="js-masonry" 
  data-masonry-options='{ "gutter": ".gutter-sizer", "itemSelector": "article"}'>

  <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
</div>
```

and the Scss

```
article {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  @include breakpoint(medium) {
    width: 49.2%;
  }
  @include breakpoint(large) {
    width: 32.26%;
  }
}
.gutter-sizer {
  width: 0%;
  @include breakpoint(medium and large) {
    width: 1.6%; //About 20px on a regular monitor at full width.
  }
}
```